# Why does Potochkin's EDT checker flag this code?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, aspectj, event-dispatch-thread

I don't understand why my code is getting flagged in this one instance.

```
myPlot.plot(serviceRef, frameMax, frameMin);
```

That line is the source location of the error. It does not make any sesne to me since there is no Swing code in the line of code. Why could this happen then?

I attached Potochkin's EDT violation checker code below:

```
    package testEDT;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * AspectJ code that checks for Swing component methods being executed OUTSIDE the Event-Dispatch-Thread.
 * 
 * (For info on why this is bad, see: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html)
 * 
 * From Alexander Potochkin's blog post here:
 * http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html
 * 
 */
aspect EdtRuleChecker{
    /** Flag for use */
    private boolean isStressChecking = true;

    /** defines any Swing method */
    public pointcut anySwingMethods(JComponent c):
         target(c) && call(* *(..));

    /** defines thread-safe methods */
    public pointcut threadSafeMethods():         
         call(* repaint(..)) || 
         call(* revalidate()) ||
         call(* invalidate()) ||
         call(* getListeners(..)) ||
         call(* add*Listener(..)) ||
         call(* remove*Listener(..));

    /** calls of any JComponent method, including subclasses */
    before(JComponent c): anySwingMethods(c) && 
                          !threadSafeMethods() &&
                          !within(EdtRuleChecker) {
        if ( !SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() && (isStressChecking || c.isShowing())) {
            System.err.println(thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation());
            System.err.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
            System.err.println();
        }
    }

    /** calls of any JComponent constructor, including subclasses */
    before(): call(JComponent+.new(..)) {
        if (isStressChecking && !SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            System.err.println(thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation());
            System.err.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature() + " *constructor*");
            System.err.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. That's a big violation on its own :-).

Comment: don't understand too, whats connection betweens single code line and a.m. test code, no idea, for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: What `JComponent` (or subclass) method is called in `plot`?

Comment: Ah you nailed it trashgod! See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "myPlot" variable is an instance of an AbstractPlot that extends JPanel! This causes the EDT checker to flag all calls made on this instance outstide the EDT, even if I am just computing a private function that does int i = 1 + 1. Now I understand :)